# iOS Auto Layout Content resistance hugging property why magic number 48

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

In apple documentation "Auto Layout Guide" -> "Auto Layout Cookbook".  The 2nd example "Nested Stack Views" which is a example of a squared ImageView horizontally stacked with a 3 vertically stacked labels & textboxes.

The guide said the content resistance of the ImageView has to be <= 48 and the textboxes content hugging has to be <= 48 for the auto-layout to work (without explanation of 48).

I tried to change to 49 or 50 or 51 and the layout somehow contains warning and the actual layout became undesirable.

So my question is, what is the meaning of 48 in this CHCR thing?

Comment: Did you try to change both the content compression resistance of the image view and the content hugging of the text fields/labels to another value? I'm pretty sure it'll work with any arbitrary value.